# Windows 10 Drive Recognition Error

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive, cmd.exe

The drive L:/ appears in File Explorer but not in cmd, diskpart, etc. It is a thumb drive that I have physically removed from my computer. When I click on the drive in File Explorer, it freezes and eventually File Explorer goes unresponsive. I also can't get any drives (including SDs) to be recognized by File Explorer. Please help!

Comment: Does BIOS show that the devices are connected? Have you checked all connections also?

Comment: Have you restarted?